# Reading from a databse in AngularJS

Tags: mysql, angularjs, database

My question is a simple enough one but I can't quite seem to find a good tutorial on it. Maybe I am not being specific enough with what I am asking but I can't really type an explanation into google and expect an answer.

So here is my question;
I currently have a website up and running on a hosting site and this hosting site allows me to have a database up on their server as well.
So my question is how do I read data from this database that I have setup using phpAdmin? Also, it is a mySQL database.

The website will be acting like a review site built I just want to use it to learn web development as well. So What I am trying to do it read articles that I will be saving in the database so I can display them on my website.

Any help or advice in regard to this is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Cylon.

Comment: I'm not expert here but I wouldn't read directly to the db with angular, better create a web service which retrieves the data of the db, preferably in JSON, then access the web service with angular.

Comment: You will need to use a server-side language such as PHP. Check with your host to see what is available. Start with something simple until you learn enough to try things you would actually use on the site. Also consider using a CMS like Joomla or Wordpress to avoid the learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

you cant read directly from a Database using **AngularJS** or any Client-side framework , you need a back-end / server-side language such as PHP ,C# ,Java..
to connect to your MySql ,MSSql... ,

so in your case your need to create PHP script which will connect to the Database and provide an interface you can access with (GET , POST methods ) using AngularJS ($http.post("url"...)

for a best practice (if you want) the Data should be in JSON format.

Comment: Okay that's perfect. Thanks. I'm fairly confident with the PHP I have atm but it's the angualrJS side I'm unsure of. Do you personally know of any good tutorials  you would recommend for angularJS $http. Just for me to compare what I have against. Most I seem to find are behind pay walls. Or maybe I am just searching the wrong thing. Thanks again.